# Angular rc3 router - Navigating to same page with different parameters

Tags: angular, routes

I'm currently trying to navigate to the same page with different id values. So if i am on `/test/1` and go to `/test/2` the url in the browser updates but the view does not refresh. I debugged ngOnInit and it did not rerun when navigating to `/test/2`. However if I go from `test/1` to `other` the routing works fine, the issue only occurs when navigating to the same route with different parameters. Has anyone else come across this? When I get some time ill upload a plunkr.

Angular 2 rc3 router `3.0.0-beta.2`

```
RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: 'Layout',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'test/:id',
                component: TestComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'other',
                component: OtherComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Thanks,
LL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you navigate to same route with different param it reuse the component. Hence `ngOnInit` won't be called again. 
You should subscribe to routeparam in `ngOnInit` and then do the view update in subscribed function

Inject Activated route in constructor

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,......) {}
```

In the `ngOnInit` method, we use the ActivatedRoute service to retrieve the parameters for our route

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
     //here goes your logic like below
this.service.getHero(id).then(hero => this.hero = hero);
   });
}
```

For more details [see](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) and section "Getting the route parameter "

Comment: Ah ok I understand. My issue was I had my service call within ngOnInit instead of my params subscription. Thanks Agarwal