# Angular2 how to rebuild a view (routing)

Tags: angular, angular-routing

How to rebuild a router? When I load the same router but with another parameter, only url changes, view stays the same. Is there some way to say the router - "Hey, rebuild yourself!"?

I need an effect like `window.location.reload()` but without reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you navigate to same route with different param it reuse the component. Hence `ngOnInit` won't be called again so you may think page is not updating.  You should subscribe to routeparam in ngOnInit and then do the view update in subscribed function

Inject Activated route in constructor

```
constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router,......) {}
In the ngOnInit method, we use the ActivatedRoute service to retrieve the parameters for our route

ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
     let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
     //here goes your logic like below
this.service.getHero(id).then(hero => this.hero = hero);
   });
}
```

Also look at another so [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38358144/652850)

Comment: Hey, thank you. It is working but weird. I'm a one router back. It is like: Cliked A -> nothing, clicked B -> redirected to A, clicked C -> redirected to B. Do yo know what is wrong?

Comment: Show us some code you may be seeing a warning on console expression has changed after being checked. Try wrapping the setter in setTimeout. Show us code related to param handling

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to refactore my code. I used inside subscription this.route.params.snapshot['id'] instead of params['id']. Thank you, you rock ;)